# buscar archivos en la terminal de linux $ comand not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu

quisiera saber como se busca un archivo en linux (desde la terminal), instale ubuntu de un video de fatz y viendo otros videos de youtube no logro acceder a ellos, veia a todos usando el simbolo `$` pero a mi no me deja, me dice el `comannd not found`.

Comment: Si pones en tu pregunta el comando completo que estabas intentando usar, posiblemente sea más fácil ayudarte

Comment: por ejemplo para acceder a descargas: 
$ descargas/ 
asi lo vi en un video, es mi primera vez en linux

Comment: El símbolo `$` por sí solo no hace nada. Suele usarse para indicar el prompt, el sitio donde la consola espera tu siguiente instrucción. Darle el nombre del directorio sin más tampoco hace nada. Quieres entrar al directorio? Buscar un directorio que tenga ese nombre? De veras que no se entiende qué intentas.

Comment: Bien, Quiero saber buscar elementos en la terminal, como seria?

Comment: Quiero entrar a descargas por ejemplo desde la terminal

Comment: `$ find` indica que vas a correr `find` como un usuario normal. Si se usa `#` entonces lo debes correr como `root`.

Answer (score 1):

En linux cada comando tiene diferentes opciones.

El comando `man` te permitirá consultar el manual. Ej: `man ls` accederas a la página del comando `ls` en el manual, y podras consultar que hace dicho comando, que opciones admite, ver ejemplos, etc.

El comando `pwd` te mostrará en que directorio te encuentras.

Para acceder a un directorio puedes usar el comando `cd`:

Ej: si estás en el directorio /home/usuario1/ (directorio del usuario usuario1), y quieres acceder al directorio Desktop (escritorio de usuario1), en este caso ambos comandos son equivalentes:

- `cd Desktop` (ruta relativa, desde el directorio donde te encuentras)
- `cd /home/usuario1/Desktop/` (ruta absoluta, desde el directorio raiz: /)

El comnado `ls` lista el contenido de un directorio. `ls -al` muestra el contenido como un listado (opción `l`), un elemento debajo del otro, e incluye los archivos y directorios ocultos (opción `a`: aquellos que comienzan con punto).

Para buscar un archivo puedes utilizar el comando `find`, tiene muchas opciones:

`find . -type f -iname *.txt`

Va a buscar en el directorio actual `.` (el directorio donde te encuentras) y sus subdirectorios, todos los archivos `-type f` cuyo nombre termine con ".txt" `-iname *.txt` (sin tener en cuenta mayúsculas y minúsculas).